# Angulajs Dependency Injection to Component

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dependency-injection, signalr

Is it possible to do dependency injection to component in angularjs

I have signalR hub factory. I want to inject my SingalR hub proxy.

I have below code ,where I am creating ngTable Component , this needs to be update dynamically by SignalRhub , so I need signalRHubProxy to be injected. How can I get this.

**Component**

```
function ngTableController($scope, $element, $attrs)
{
}
app.component('ngTable', {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/ngTable.html',
    controller: ngTableController,


});
```

**Factory**

'use strict';

```
app.factory('signalRHubProxy', ['$rootScope', 'signalRServer',
    function ($rootScope, signalRServer) {

        function signalRHubProxyFactory(serverUrl, hubName, startOptions) {
            var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRServer);
            var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
            connection.start(startOptions).done(function () { });

            return {
                on: function (eventName, callback) {
                    proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            if (callback) {
                                callback(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                off: function (eventName, callback) {
                    proxy.off(eventName, function (result) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            if (callback) {
                                callback(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                invoke: function (methodName, callback) {
                    proxy.invoke(methodName)
                        .done(function (result) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                if (callback) {
                                    callback(result);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                },
                connection: connection
            };
        };

        return signalRHubProxyFactory;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,

I got the answer after trail and error method

```
app.component('ngTable', {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/ngTable.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'signalRHubProxy', ngTableController]


});
```